# IMPORTXML Google resource at url

Tags: xml, google-sheets, feed

I want to import a XML feed from one of our suppliers but Google sheets gives the error resource at url content exceeded maximum size. Is there a script to circumvent this issue? I checked several threads but didn't see a solution.This is the [xml feed](https://www.pfconcept.com/portal/datafeed/stockfeed_9019cb0e_1bfc_b786_e511_cb8235772846_v2.1.xml)

The feed is automatically refreshed twice per day. Is there a way to pull the new data as well twice per day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
const IMPORTALL = url => Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());

=IMPORTALL("https://www.pfconcept.com/portal/datafeed/stockfeed_9019cb0e_1bfc_b786_e511_cb8235772846_v2.1.xml")
```

[image]